# Prepopulate Name field with default value

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, urlhacking, button-overrides

I have a Publication object. Publications might have a very long names, longer than 80 characters. That is why Name is suppose to be populated from workflow field update, using substring from custom text field.

How can I override New button on the publication tab:
[image]

I created the following custom button, but I do not know how to replace new button with it.

[image]

I read many posts online, but could not figure solution for my case.

Please advise.

**EDIT**
I created a visual page which works with custom fields, but when I try to use ID of Name field it does not prepopulate the Name field. Do I retrieve the wrong ID, or should I use some other parameter?

URL after I click on Name field in Setup:

```
https://cs14.salesforce.com/p/setup/field/StandardFieldAttributes/d?id=Name&type=01Ia0000002Rgjl&retURL=%2F01Ia0000002Rgjl%3Fsetupid%3DCustomObjects&setupid=CustomObjects&rowsperpage=10000
```

VF page script:

```
<apex:page standardController="Publication__c">
  <script>
      window.top.location.href = '/a0f/e?nooverride=1&01Ia0000002Rgjl=Your+Default+Value';
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Similar question and solution:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008ocDIAQ

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't modify the behavior of that particular button.

Comment: Can I then modify Save button to prepopulate Name field before saving a new record ?

Comment: I also found related solution here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008ocDIAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot replace that particular button with a custom button.

However, you can override the standard New button for your object which overrides that button.  See the [Salesforce help page for Overriding Standard Buttons](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=links_customize_override.htm&language=en_US) for the detailed steps.  The part that varies from the documented steps is the code which I’ve detailed next.

You need to create a Visualforce page that uses a standard controller.  That is done by creating a page and setting the [`<apex:page/>’s`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm) standardController attribute to your custom object..

Technically, you could just move your URL hack into the Visualforce page and be done with it:

```
<apex:page standardController=“Publication__c”>
  <script>
      window.top.location.href = ‘/a0f/e?nooverride=1&01Ia0000asdf32123d=Your+Default+Value’;
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Note that you need to specify the `nooverride=1` parameter to ensure that you get redirected to the standard New page and not right back to your override.

Your question is a bit confusing, because you state that you need to set a value in a Workflow Rule, but then you also discuss having prepopulating a default value.  The above answers the prepopulate name field with default value question (i.e., the title of your actual question).   If you need to set a value on a Save of a record you can just use a Workflow Rule and Workflow Field Update. See the [Salesforce help page on Creating Workflow Rules](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_rules.htm) for more on that.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I need to prepopulate Name field because Workflow Field Update will not work with Name field on Save. Name should have at least some default value. It is a work around for me. After it has a default value, Workflow Rule will be able to update it.